# Self Sizing Cell in Swift, how do I make constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, sidebar

I'm trying to do a sidebar with self sizing cells in swift. I found this great tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

As far as I know you need 3 things to make a self sizing cell:

1. Define auto layout constraints for your prototype cell
2. Specify the estimatedRowHeight of your table view
3. Set the rowHeight of your table view to UITableViewAutomaticDimension

The last two are covered in the tutorial by code, but the first one is explained by the story board, and my problem is how do I implement it by code??

I have this method where I get my custom cell, I think that I have to implement the constraints(in the tutorial you can see what kind of constrains) here but I don't know how, so please could you give me some help?

```
override func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!),   cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) -> UITableViewCell{ 

 if cell == nil {

    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")

    cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()

        let selectedView:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.frame.size.width, height: cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)


    cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView

    //asignar valores a la celda

    cell!.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    cell!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)



                   }

    return cell!


   }
```

Update 1:
  [image: The text goes beyond the 3rd break of line un the 1st an 3rd row]

The text goes beyond the 3rd break of line in the 1st and the 3rd row, but here only show me max. of 3 breaklines

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't add layout constraints in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`.

You should not instantiate a table view cell in that method yourself. Instead, you should register one with the UITableView (probably in the `viewDidLoad()` method of your view controller) ([`registerClass(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) or [`registerNib(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:)).

In `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` you use [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) to get an instance of the cell. The table view will reuse cells as you scroll, so that it doesn't have to create new ones all the time. Essentially, let's say you never see more than 15 cells on screen at the same time, then there won't be more than that many instances.

Now, when you register your table view cells (see above) you should probably subclass `UITableViewCell` and then either set your layout constraints in code (maybe override `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`) or you can create a .nib file and use that. Then you can set up the constraints in Xcode through the graphical UI.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi thomas,thanks for your answer and excuse me if I ask silly questions, but I'm new in iOS Development. So I'm interested in the .nib file part, so you can make that kind of file and the use it in your code? It remind me of how you declare a view in android in the xml file and then yu can use it in your code, is that the case here or I'm totally lost xD?

Comment: To use a .nib file, add a new "User Interface" file to your project and select the empty template. Then drag a single UITableViewCell into it and set it up. If you're subclassing it, change the class to your subclass. Make sure to put the correct Cell Reuse Identifier in there. Make sure there is only that one single UITableViewCell in there.

Comment: I'm very new to Android development, but yes, from my understanding this is equivalent to a view in an xml file in Android.

Comment: Cool! I will try with the .nib thing tomorrow, I will tell you if it work : )

Answer (score 0):

I found a good function to make cell dynamic size

```
func dynamicHeight(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

        label.font = font
        label.text = text

        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height

    }
```

Call this function in heightForRowAtIndexPath

I hope it works.

Comment: I use your code and didn't work, but when I use the method: lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping i get better results but the row stopped growing at the 3rd break of line (I will update my post with an image of this result). Thanks I hope you have another solution. : )

Comment: The cells aren't really self-sizing with this solution are they.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

First add this two functions in your class

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Second in order to make the UITableViewAutomaticDimension work make sure you have added all the left, right, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view.