# reusing a cell in table view in the wrong way? my rows get repeated values when scrolling on my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to implement a table by code, so far so good but when I scroll down and up in my table my rows went crazy, I did a little research and I think its because of the way I reuse my cells, but the examples I found were all in Obj- C, So could you please help me to understand the problem? Here are my function where I implement the cells:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!),   cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) -> UITableViewCell{


    let sectionA = seccionesDiccionario[indexPath.section]
    let sectionName = tableDataSwiftDictionary[sectionA]!


    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellId") as? UITableViewCell


    if cell == nil {

    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")

    cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()

    let selectedView:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.frame.size.width, height: cell!.frame.size.height))
    selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)

    cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
    cell!.textLabel?.text  = sectionName[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell!.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell!.textLabel?.sizeToFit()

                   }

    return cell!

}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I scroll down and up in my table my rows went crazy

- what do you mean by 'went crazy'.

One thing that I can see in the above code: You should move the text assignment out of the if statement. You want the 'textLabel' to show the String in the 'sectionName' array at the given indexPath.row. Currently, you are creating some cells and then - when you start scrolling your tableView - the cells are reused but the textLabel's text is not set, so it will always show its initial value.

Move this line

```
cell!.textLabel?.text  = sectionName[indexPath.row]
```

out of the if{} block. Maybe that's all you need to do here.

EDIT

btw: since you're calling `sizeToFit` on the textLabel, I assume you want the cell to be high enough to display all the text. Note that `sizeToFit` will not be enough in order to achieve that. You'll have to either use Auto-sizing cells using AutoLayout (> iOS8) or implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and return the calculated cell height there.

Comment: thanks : ) I will try it!, and I mean that my rows get repeated values and change the initial position

Comment: Hi Cabus, your solution works : D thanks!, by the way, could you check my other question? its about the auto-high of my cell (the thing that you kindly mention on your edit of this post). Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369777/self-sizing-cell-in-swift-how-do-i-make-constraints-programmatically